# How to observe changes on stream with Bloc

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, rxdart

i have problem with observing my firestore database in my bloc:

```
  @override
  Stream<ProjectsState> mapEventToState(
     ProjectsEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is LoadData)
        yield* repo.observeData().map((data) => DataLoadSuccess(data));
}
```

This work but my bloc is not responding anymore for other events. It is 'bloced'

Do you have any idea?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`yield*` will return all the elements in a stream until that stream ends. Firestore streams are created in such a way that they will never be closed (at least not until they are garbage collected). As such, your `mapEventToState` method is now in a state where it will always be waiting for the next element in the store to come.

Instead of using `yield*`, you could just use `yield` and return a single value by calling `.first` on the stream.

```dart
yield repo.observeData().map((data) => DataLoadSuccess(data)).first;
```

Comment: the whole idea of observing items in database is to get notify when items changes. So Your solution did not help. I guess bypassing bloc and subscribing directly to widget (StreamBuilder) should work but it is not clean code

Comment: @Pawelo In that case you want to create a separate repository class that monitors the stream and notifies the bloc for changes. You shouldn't be doing the listening within the bloc itself.

Comment: Thank you. I end up with listen rx in bloc constructor and sending event from there